# Why I can't input my post data with mod_security is turn on?

Tags: php, apache, mod-security

It is possible for input posting data with mod_security is turn on?

I'm using CI3 but now I can't input or edit any data because mod_security is turn on so Should I turn it off? but it may not security for hacker right?

Do you have any solution?

Comment: Please give details from error log and/or audit log which rule failed and also which rules ModSecurity rules you have installed.